# How can I resolve the error The HGFS kernel module was not found after upgrading VMWare for Laravel Homestead?

Tags: laravel, vagrant, vmware, homestead

After upgrading VMWare to a new version Homestead is no longer able to find the shared folders.  Alos, when running `vagrant up` from the Homestead directory I see this error during the startup process:

`The HGFS kernel module was not found on the running virtual machine.
This must be installed for shared folders to work properly. Please
install the VMware tools within the guest and try again. Note that
the VMware tools installation will succeed even if HGFS fails
to properly install. Carefully read the output of the VMware tools
installation to verify the HGFS kernel modules were installed properly.`

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When upgrading VMWare to a new version, a new version of the VMWare tools also needs to be installed on the Homestead virtual machine to match the new version of VMWare .  However,  This is a little more involved than expected because Homestead does not include the header files.  You can fix this by following these directions:

1. Change to the Homestead directory on your host
2. Run vagrant up as usual
3. Wait for the Homestead VM to load - you will see the HGFS error.  You can also abort instead of waiting by pressing ctrl or cmd  - C
4. The Homestead VM should be started now - just without shared folder support.  Login to the vm as normal using something like `ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222`
5. Run the following commands at the terminal:

`sudo apt-get install -y build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
sudo vmware-config-tools.pl`

This will install the kernel headers required to build VMWare tools as well as run the configuration setup for vmware on the Homestead VM.

You will answer a number of questions - just use the defaults **except** for the one about *VMware automatic kernel modules*.

**Answer yes** to this question and you should not have this problem again (or at least you will not have this again until the Homestead box is replaced).

After this go back to your host machine and run:

`vagrant halt
vagrant up`

and everything will work as expected.  You will no longer see the error about HGFS and the shared folders will be available.

Comment: Thanks this worked :-) I believe there's a little typo on the first of the two command lines, because the part "sudo apt-get install" is there twice.